# How to find the smallest count in my BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes

What I'm trying to do right now is find the minimum value of repeat count in my binary search tree (BST).

What this means is that the BST is normal when inserting values, but then when it gets the same value twice it instead will increment the value of repeat count, which the tree isn't dependent on (so I can't just go left for the minimum value).

I have tried getting the minimum value but it always comes up short. The function trying to get the smallest is `findSmallest`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 0; //random number

    Random rnum = new Random();
    SBT sbt = new SBT();

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        x = rnum.nextInt(20) + 1;
        sbt.insert(x);
    }

    sbt.printLargestCount();
    sbt.printSmallestCount();
    sbt.FS();
    sbt.deleteBoth();
    System.out.println("Sum of the key values is:   " + sbt.sumKeyValue());
    System.out.println("Sum of the repeat counts is: " + sbt.sumReapeatCount());

    sbt.inorder();
}
```

Here is the function trying to get the value I am right now trying to go through all the node in the tree and comparing them to the current smallest value. 
If the nodes `repeatCount` is smaller that value it will change value and a global node `smallestCount`.

I have added those globals below.

```
private BSTNode root;     
private BSTNode largestCount;
private BSTNode smallestCount;
private int sumKeyVal;
public void FS(){
    findSmallest(root, 0);
    System.out.println("data is: " + smallestCount.data + " repeatCount is: " + smallestCount.repeatCount);
}
private void findSmallest(BSTNode r, int val){
    if(r == null) return;
    if(r == root)val = r.repeatCount;

    if(r.repeatCount < val){
        val = r.repeatCount;
        smallestCount = r;
        System.out.println(val);
    }
    if(r.right == null && r.left == null)
        return;         
    else if(r.left != null)
        findSmallest(r.left,val);
    else if(r.right != null)
        findSmallest(r.right,val);
}          

private BSTNode insert(int x, BSTNode t){
    if (t == null){
        t = new BSTNode(x);
        smallestCount = t;
    }
    else if (x < t.data)
        t.left = insert( x, t.left );
    else if (x > t.data)
        t.right = insert( x, t.right );
    else
        t.height = max( height( t.left ), height( t.right ) ) + 1;
    return t;
}
private int height(BSTNode t ) {
    return t == null ? -1 : t.height;
}
// Function to max of left/right node
private int max(int lhs, int rhs) {
    return lhs > rhs ? lhs : rhs;
}
```

Here is the node class used:

```
public class BSTNode {

    BSTNode left, right;
    int data;
    int height;
    int repeatCount;

    /* Constructor */
    public BSTNode(){
        left = null;
        right = null;
        data = 0;
        height = 0;
        repeatCount = 0;
    }
    /* Constructor */
    public BSTNode(int n){
        left = null;
        right = null;
        data = n;
        height = 0;
        repeatCount = 0;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I figured it out and tested the code seems to work. Below is the block of code changed.

```
public void FS(){
             findSmallest(root, 0);
         }
         private int findSmallest(BSTNode r, int val){
             if(r == null) return val;
             if(r == root)val = r.repeatCount;

             if(r.repeatCount < val){
                 val = r.repeatCount;
                 smallestCount = r;
             }

             val = findSmallest(r.left,val);    
             val = findSmallest(r.right,val);

             return val;

     }
```

> Getting rid of the if else statements and going with a check for null at the begging traversed through the tree and kept the smallest along the way.